# How to fetch records from mysql database and display 10 results per page using Jquery Pager Plugin. Please Help

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pagination, paging

I came to know the Jquery Pager Plugin is nice. But in the demo of that plugin they used only some texts to display in the paging. But I need to display the database recordsets results in paging. I need help Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Pager plugin ...you probably mean http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Pager ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a page button is clicked your

```
buttonClickCallback: function(pageclickednumber) { 
}
```

function is called. Make an [ajax request](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax) containing this `pageclickednumber`. Can be as simple as

```
buttonClickCallback: function(pageclickednumber) { 
  $('#results').load('your/script.php?page='+pageclickednumber);
}
```

Your server-side script then calculates which records it must fetch and send back to the client. Something like `$offset = $page*$itemsPerPage;`